# Highcharts populate the categories with live data from MySQL

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have read a number of posts but none of them seem to cover my issue.

I am trying to complete a script that displays data in a chart (HighCharts).

All works well but I would like to populate the categories with data pulled from an MySQL data table. So far I have pulled the data for the chart but not the categories. I do not know how to get the AName (my category) to display in the categories [].

Any anyone help, many thanks in advance.

My Query script retunrs:
[{"name":"AName","data":["Astana","India","Arik","Asiana","British","Pacific","Egypt","Ethio ","Etihad","Gulf","Korean","Kuwait","Brunei","SriLan"]},
{"name":"Sat","data":[93.8,86.4,85.4,83.9,84.3,84.2,89.4,88.9,80.5,83.8,82.7,80.6,83.8,80.2]}]

the script to produce the chart:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("charts_get_data.php", function(json) {

    $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 30,
                marginBottom: 110
            },
            title: {
                text: ' Crew Feedback Overall Satisfaction %',
                x: -20, //center
        style: {
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
        color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '11px'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [],
    labels: {
            style: {
                color: '#F00',
                font: '11px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
    }
            },
            yAxis: {
    max:100,
    showFirstLabel: false,
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:2,
        gridLineColor:'#ddd',
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage',
        style: {
                fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
        color: '#000000',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: '11px'
                }
                },
                plotLines: [{

                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                   return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                   this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: json
        });
    });

});

});
```

Comment: in this case , you can use category = yourResult.data simply, btw why not you parse the data while fetching from sql.keep it in desired format

Comment: @Nishith Chaturvedi, Hi and thanks for your help again. Completely stuck with this. How and where would I use "category = yourResult.data". The return from the query has "array_push($result,$categories);" Thanks again.

Comment: is this working for you?

Comment: See this fiddle, I made changes for you function.. copy it and replace in your code http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/779gxLr6/       hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** If you can get json response in desired format like below json,you can loop through multiple name/series but categories must be in array of items not as lists. updated fiddle for this response at [This fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2ck3ukg6/5/)

```
  {"name":"AName","Categories":    ["Astana","India","Arik","Asiana","British","Pacific","Egypt","Ethio     ","Etihad","Gulf","Korean","Kuwait","Brunei","SriLan"],"data":    [93.8,86.4,85.4,83.9,84.3,84.2,89.4,88.9,80.5,83.8,82.7,80.6,83.8,80.2]}
```

Use following code,if you don't want to change output of your json

```
  var categories=[];
      var data2 =[];

          var abc =[{"name":"AName","data":["Astana","India","Arik","Asiana","British","Pacific","Egypt","Ethio   ","Etihad","Gulf","Korean","Kuwait","Brunei","SriLan"]},{"name":"Sat","data":  [93.8,86.4,85.4,83.9,84.3,84.2,89.4,88.9,80.5,83.8,82.7,80.6,83.8,80.2]}];
     $.each(abc,function(i,el)
 { if (el.name=="AName")
         categories = el.data;
 else
     data2.push(el);


});
```

See working [Fiddle with your data](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/2ck3ukg6/3/)

Comment: Hi again, Thank you for the code and the fiddle but I still can't see how I use the result of the call to the data. I have "$.getJSON("charts_get_data.php", function(json) {" but how can I get that in to the chart script. I am not good at JQ!uery as you can see.

Comment: use this >> $.getJSON("charts_get_data.php", function(json) { $.each(json,function(i,el)
 { if (el.name=="AName")
         categories = el.data;
 else
     data2.push(el);


}); });

Comment: and then use data2 in series and categories in highcharts categories: as I did in fiddle

Comment: See this fiddle, I have written code inside  your php  function $.getJSON("charts_get_data.php", function(json) {       .. copy it and replace in your code jsfiddle.net/Nishith/779gxLr6 hope it will help you